# How to run metapost?

Tags: ubuntu, metapost

I have tried to run metapost with the command:

```
mpost myfigure.mp
```

I got an error which I've seen a lot of people ask about:

> Sorry, I can't find the 'mpost' preload file; will try 'plain'.
>   I can't find the 'plain' preload file!

But for me, the solution of running:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive
```

made no difference.

How exactly is metapost run?

Comment: There is no single texlive package is Ubuntu it is split up in lots and lots (very confusing for the user, and why I use upstream texlive instead. Nevertheless, try searching `sudo apt update` and then `apt-cache search metapost` (the latter does not need sudo)

Comment: `mpost` is looking for `/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/metapost/base/mpost.mp` and `/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/metapost/base/plain.mp` but it can't find them on your system.... (or ..2018.. if you are more up to date than me)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the MetaPost binary is already installed on your system, Ubuntu does not install any MetaPost format by default. Like daleif mentioned in a comment you could avoid this confusing situation by [using upstream TeXLive](https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html) or you can install the formats:

Run

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-metapost
```

Then the command

```
mpost myfigure.mp
```

works.

If you want to use the [MetaFun](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/metafun-p.pdf) extensions, you need `metafun.mp` from ConTeXt. To install ConTeXt using Ubuntu packages, just run

```
sudo apt-get install context
```

Then you can use MetaPost with the MetaFun format using

```
mpost '@metafun' myfigure.mp
```

Comment: sudo apt-get install texlive-metapost did the tick for me in Ubuntu 16.04!